# Windows XP Font used in Input Elements

Tags: windows-xp

What font is used for the input and drop down elements in the default green/blue windows xp theme?

Here is a picture of an input element with the font I am looking for.

[image: Windows xp input element]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the tool at [WhatTheFont](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) to match your font. I tried it on the screenshot you provided, but it was too small to recognize it.

The default system font used in Windows XP is Tahoma. See this Microsoft [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823033). To me the sample you posted doesn't quite match Tahoma, but it's close.

Comment: After some searching it appears the font is Trebuchet MS, but I could be wrong.  It is very difficult to notice any differences in such a small size.

Answer (score 0):

A tool like [wfspy](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/wfspy.aspx) should be able to show you what font is in use.  wfspy claims to help you to view properties of any window form control in the system.